# GCP Cloud Functions から Cloud Shellにインストールした実行ファイルを起動したい

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP Cloud Functions上から、自分でインストールしたGoの実行ファイルをCloud Functionsから起動したいです。

調べたところ、Node.jsから `execSync()` 関数を呼ぶとシステムで用意されたコマンドを呼べそうでしたので、引数として実行ファイルを置いたパスを入れたのですが、以下のようなエラーが返ってきました。

```
Command failed: <commandname> <--args> 
/bin/sh: 1: <commandname>: not found
```

今まで試したパスは以下です：

- home直下
- /usr/local/bin
- /tmp
- /workspace

Cloud Shell（VMインスタンス）に保存した実行ファイルはどこに置き、どのように呼べばよいのかご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけますか。

Comment: エラーメッセージも質問中に含めておくと、回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。エラーメッセージを本文に追加しました。

Comment: 自己解決しました。方法は「カスタム実行バイナリを、コード（index.js）と同じディレクトリに置く」です。呼び出し方はこのようにして、返り値を受け取ることが出来ました。

const result =  execSync(`custom-binary --option`).toString();